# Parsing string in sections with NSScanner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsscanner

I am trying to parse a string with a format like this:

```
*date1:
- band1.1 @ venue1.1.
- band1.2 @ venue1.2.
*date2:
- band 2.1 @ venue2.1.
- band 2.2 @ venue2.2.
```

etc

The number of dates and the number of bands and the associated venue can vary. I am using code based on the example at the bottom of [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html).

I am using this snippet of code (I left out the bits at the bottom as they are irrelevant, but yes, I do close the loops etc.):

```
 NSScanner *scanner1 = [NSScanner scannerWithString:contents];
NSCharacterSet *colon = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"];
NSCharacterSet *at = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"@"];
NSCharacterSet *dot = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"."];
NSLog(@"scanner starting");

while ([scanner1 isAtEnd] == NO) {
    if ([scanner1 scanString:@"*" intoString:NULL] && [scanner1 scanUpToCharactersFromSet:colon intoString:&tempDate] && [scanner1 scanString:@":" intoString:NULL]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", tempDate);
        if ([scanner1 scanString:@"-" intoString:NULL] && [scanner1 scanUpToCharactersFromSet:at intoString:&tempBands] && [scanner1 scanString:@"@" intoString:NULL] && [scanner1 scanUpToCharactersFromSet:dot intoString:&tempVenue]
            &&[scanner1 scanString:@"." intoString:NULL]) 
        {
            NSLog(@"%@ %@", tempBands, tempVenue);
        }
    }
}   NSLog(@"ended scanning");
```

Currently, the first date is parsed and printed to the console, and the first venue and band of that date are printed. "ended scanning" is never printed. I have been battling this for hours and I am unsure of what to do now. I have a feeling that I do not understand the inner workings of NSScanner and there is probably a different way to tackle this problem. Maybe I need a second scanner?

Comment: Second loop? You haven't shown us a second loop here. What you have done so far seems fine.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the second if loop. So there is a while loop, an if loop (if1) inside it, then the if loop inside that one (if2). Currently, the scanner gets stuck inside if1 (it never exits) and it enters if2 only once when it should do multiple times.

Comment: An if statement is not a loop. It's impossible for it to get "stuck" there. Can you tell us exactly what is printed out and what tempDate, tempBands, and tempVenue contain?

Comment: I meant the while loop (the while loop only really contains if1 anyway. I changed if2 to print a string containing the tempBand, tempDate and tempVenue together. So far, the program prints the first date (tempDate) on its own, then the first entry under that date.

Comment: I have edited my original post based on the feedback you gave. Thank you for the help so far, I wasn't able to copy and paste my code then edit it after, so I skipped some sections of code and made it unclear to you and myself what was really going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first round of the while loop, the scanner's position is right after `"venue1."`. The next round of the loop starts with scanning an asterisk, which fails (returns NO) because the next (non-whitespace) character is a dash. Therefore, the body of the if statement isn't executed and the scanner's position is not advanced any further, resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you so much! I fixed this problem with a simple goto statement (I keep hearing about how bad they are to use, but my code actually  makes more sense when I use one now. Problem solved.